# iOS11 Search bar blank space above and below (iPhone X simulator)

Tags: xcode, uitableview, search, ios11

When search is active a blank space is above and below search bar in iOS 11. I have search bar view inside the tableview. It seems that search bar is not stretching up. Or what else is wrong?

Hi guys, if someone needs it, these lines do the trick in 
viewDidLoad method:

```
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) 
    { 
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=YES;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES; 
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you read Apple's documentation and watched their Designing for iPhone X video?

Comment: Hi, yes but problem still persist, i walk in circle :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use safe area guide for design. more info refer this link https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/

Comment: If help that doc gives positive response.